# Name class error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
def returnComparison(comparison, *args):
   # Sample:
   #   returnComparison('greater than', 10, 20, 55) --> 55
   if comparison == "greater than":
      return max(args)
   elif comparison == "less than":
      return min(args)
   else:
      flag = True
      for arg in range(args-1):
         if args[arg] != args[arg+1]:
            flag = False
      return flag

    Error: <class 'NameError'>!
```

Comment: What is the question here

Comment: im trying to figure out whats wrong with the code

Comment: This does give an error, but it's not a `NameError`, it's a `TypeError`.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: Then inorder to get some help  you better add some description what you 're going to do with this and what are the sample inputs and what is the expected out put you want so on. you just place a code here people will down vote?

Comment: the goal is to fix the code. i have no idea what its supposed to do

Comment: You coded a piece of code that you don't know what it's suppose to do? Or did you copy someone's code and it's not working and you don't know what you've copied? Either way you need to find out what the code is suppose to do so we can help you. Most of us won't waste time guessing what the code is suppose to do. Edit your question with more details please.

Comment: How can you fix something if you don't even know what it is supposed to do and you also don't understand the programming language? Makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want help with fixing the exception you get when the script gets into the `else` statement.

The problem here is very simple. You are subtracting an integer from a tuple.

In fact, the bigger mistake here is that you are not using the `range()` function properly. You should pass an integer to it for it to work.

The solution is very simple. Change line 10 of your code to: `for arg in range(len(args)-1):` The `len()` function returns the length of the args tuple.

So, your code will end up like this:

```
def returnComparison(comparison, *args):
   # Sample:
   #   returnComparison('greater than', 10, 20, 55) --> 55
   if comparison == "greater than":
      return max(args)
   elif comparison == "less than":
      return min(args)
   else:
      flag = True
      for arg in range(len(args)-1):
         if args[arg] != args[arg+1]:
            flag = False
      return flag
```

Good luck!